# xps 13 9310 developer edition ubuntu 20.04 problems with HEVC encoded video files

Tags: drivers, dell, video, xps, hevc

I have an xps13 9310 with:

---

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1195G7 @ 2.90GHz × 8

Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

---

when trying HEVC (MPEG-H Part 2/HEVC H.265) encoded videos, doesn't play them smoothly! I can't imagine that this might be a hardware problem?

I already have installed the ubuntu restricted package but this didn't help at all! Am I missing some additional software?

Thank you

---

**I use the DELL installed ubuntu OS:**

Linux version 5.10.0-1057-oem (buildd@lcy02-amd64-040) (gcc (Ubun tu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #61-Ubun tu SMP Thu Jan 13 15:06:11 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.10.0-1057.61-oem 5.10.83)

**I use VLC indeed and here is the mediainfo of the file:**

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 1
Codec ID                                 : mp41 (mp41)
File size                                : 336 MiB
Duration                                 : 28 s 111 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 100 Mb/s

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main@L6@Main
Codec ID                                 : hvc1
Codec ID/Info                            : High Efficiency Video Coding
Duration                                 : 28 s 111 ms
Bit rate                                 : 100 Mb/s
Width                                    : 5 312 pixels
Height                                   : 2 988 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 59.940 (60000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.105
Stream size                              : 335 MiB (100%)
Color range                              : Full
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Codec configuration box                  : hvcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 28 s 96 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192 kb/s
Nominal bit rate                         : 48.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 649 KiB (0%)

Other #1
ID                                       : 3
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : QuickTime TC
Duration                                 : 28 s 111 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Frame rate                               : 59.940 (60000/1001) FPS
Time code of first frame                 : 17:16:27:15

Other #2
Type                                     : meta
Duration                                 : 28 s 110 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Duration_LastFrame                       : -919
```

Comment: You probably need a newer kernel. Is Ubuntu 20.04 factory installed?

Comment: with that kind of hardware there should be no problem in playing hevc files. Can you post some additional info, e.g. player you are using (I suggest try VLC) and the output of something like Mediainfo of one of the video files that have trouble running?

Comment: Using 20.04 and VLC play HEVC files with no issues.

Comment: on the same hqrdware like mine?